# How can I get same result of date on browser from real data in mysql? (timezone)

Tags: mysql, node.js, linux, express, timezone

At first, I'm Korean and today is 2017-11-20.

I'm using CentOS7, Nodejs, express and mariadb(mysql).

I think I have a problem about timezone.

in my CentOS7,

```
#date
Mon Nov 20 19:30:16 KST 2017
```

in my mysql,

```
> SELECT now();
2017-11-20 19:34:05
> SELECT * FROM mytable
------------------
| ID | dodate    |
-----------------
| 1  | 2017-11-20|
------------------
```

in my app.js,

```
...
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    ...   
    var sql = ‘SELECT dodate FROM mytable’;
    conn.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else{
        res.send(rows);
    }
    ...   
});
...
```

result is, (on browser)

```
[{"dodate":"2017-11-19T15:00:00:00.000z"}]
```

but I wanted the result of

```
2017-11-20
```

not

```
2017-11-19
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your `dodate` column has the datatype of `DATETIME`. Datatypes of `TIMESTAMP` get translated.

Comment: I changed datatype form date to timestamp. But it doesn't work.

Comment: "It doesn't work" can mean anything from "my server caught fire and my data center burned to the ground" to "My value was two minutes off."  It will help you as a developer, and the people trying to answer your questions, if you describe your problems as precisely as possible.

Comment: Thanks. My English is not good. So I'm sorry I can't describe my problem well.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var sql = ‘SELECT dodate FROM date(mytable)’;
```